# Putting a check box on and Access Report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

i am trying to build a check box into and access report which will allow the user to select the desired records from a areport.  Unfortunately, upon clicking on the box, the box is highlighted but the check mark does not arrive. Does anyone know how to fix this.
?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you have the wrong approach by trying to use a report as your source. Most important, a report is "Read-Only", thus you would never be able to just click and change the state of an object to select a record. try it - you can't change any fields. This is the second time you have asked this same question in this forum, so you may want to rethink the approach.

Can you somehow get a report to function? Sure, but the solution is insane (IMO).  Why not create a FORM, have the user select whatever rows they want, then click a "Produce Report" button?

Comment: I think there is a miscommunication here.  You can absolutely use a report as a form to allow for data manipulation and for my use (and my users) there is a big advantage in the presentation of how they see their data and how they can interact with it..  Working with Hans (and then with a colleague) we got a pop up window to allow the user to click on a record on and embedded report and have access to do a zoom in on that records memo field, and then have the opportunity to change its content. I need the same type of functionality but with a yes/no box .

Comment: to allow users export records to another form where they can work on the records.  The report allows for a strategic, user friendly way to Group the information and allow the user to save time and space while viewing and scrolling.

Comment: The following is a zoom box which opens upon clicking on a control embedded in my report allowing the user to change the contents of a record.

Comment: Private Sub Notes_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmZoom2", View:=acNormal, WhereCondition:="[ID] = " & Me.txtPrimaryKey, WindowMode:=acDialog, OpenArgs:=Me.ID_Event
    
End Sub

Comment: Yes, I am aware of your popup FORM solution to clicking on a REPORT field, but I am unaware of ANY ability to change data directly on a report without doing something like your popup form. If I am ill-informed, please point me to an explanation. As for your checkbox, why not just employ your same popup solution?

Comment: Like i said, there could be some miscomunication. I am new to Access and programming and often get lost in the Language. My goal is to allow the user to select records by placing an X while looking at the report and then having the option of going to a another form where there records selected will be waiting for them on a user screen which will capture much more detail than what the report displays. Thats all. Perhaps your suggestion is the way to go but I still dont understand the best way to let the user flag the records prior to going to the next screen.

Comment: Possibly you could investigate something like a double-click event on a row would invoke conditional formatting that would highlight the row on the report with a different background color, or BOLD a field? At the end you would need to see which rows have different color and pass those keys to your next form.

Comment: Yes, that idea is even better and exactly what i am looking for. Unfortunately, I am not at that level (yet) and need help..  Even checking the internet I get stuck

Comment: Do you have any idea on the best way to ask someone how to walk me through something like that??  I take good notes and make it a point to not have to ask the same question (once answered) again.

Comment: Good news/bad news - you could use conditional formatting to change a row color; but it is based on a value in a field in a row. Yes, you could have the double-click event update a checkbox in a table and requery the report, but then the check would show and you don't need conditional formatting (confusing? yes!) A small report, based on a simple query / table would refresh quickly, but each refresh would take user back to top of report. One page = not a big deal; more than 1 page = unhappy user. I really think a form is a better approach for edit / select... gotta get some sleep now...

Comment: OK., thanks alot.. Im off to work anyway..  Ill let you know what my experts come up with today...

Comment: Mr. Dunn..  Just a note, today i worked on the problem with a great programmer in my office an in a few short minutes we found the optimal solution.  Basically, embedded i the report, I put a short text field in the form of a little square. Upon clicking on it the the code (below) updates the field to a value. Using conditional formatting i made so that the White box turns bright red upon clicking on it. from there the user can check all the records he pleases of which a nice bright red box flags the record. At the end there is a button underneath which brings all the selected records to the

Comment: work form to the user to work on all the select items without the "noise" of the un interesting records.   By the way, there was no problem regarding automatically scrolling to the top of the report upon the requery/refresh.

Comment: Private Sub DeepDive_Click()

CurrentDb.Execute "update tblContactReporting03 set DeepDive='yes' where [ID]=" & Me.ID
Me.Requery
End Sub

Comment: Glad that you got this to work. One word of caution is you may want to 'toggle' the "DeepDive" value if a user clicks again. If by accident they click on an unchecked box, they need a way to undo what they did.

Comment: Already there Mr. Dunn..  Upon double clicking, the field turns null..  (otherwise you wouldnt be able to erase your choice if you further decided that you didnt need the record)

Comment: Private Sub DeepDive_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
CurrentDb.Execute "update tblContactReporting03 set DeepDive=null where [ID]=" & Me.ID
Me.Requery
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Resolution workaround: a txt box (linked to an underlying field in the table) where upon clicking the box the field gets updated. With conditional formatting the box changes colour allowing a nice visual aspect for its user..   PS - use double click event to undo the update...

Private Sub DeepDive_Click() CurrentDb.Execute "update tblContactReporting03 set DeepDive='yes' where [ID]=" & Me.ID Me.Requery End Sub